# ENOENT error trying to spawn process 'Terminal.App' in NodeJs to see if screen sharing is enabled

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, macos-big-sur

I am trying to spawn Terminal.App and pass it some args to see whether screen sharing is enabled on the machine. Here's my code

```
import { spawn } from 'child_process';
const bat = spawn ('/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app', ['arch']);
```

I get an uncaught exception: Error spawn /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app ENOENT.

I also got an error when I just did: Error spawn Terminal.app ENOENT

```
import { spawn } from 'child_process';
spawn ('Terminal.app', ['arch']);
```

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS's `spawn` function takes a command, not a Terminal, as its first parameter.

For example:

```
import { spawn } from 'child_process';
spawn('arch');
```

More reference [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options).

Comment: An example is given in the page I linked regarding `ls -lh /usr`. Basically, you just have to listen to `stdout` events. The example given in the NodeJS page is applicable to your needs.

Comment: Yeah, i was asking because when i just did 'arch' on the regular terminal, i got i386 but when i did spawn ('arch') it printed out a wierd <Buffer 21 38 42 00> something like that so was wondering what was going on there.